# Optimize ResultSet iteration

Tags: performance

I have a SQL query that return 92000 rows, and when i use the while  with ResultSet.next(), it spend a lot of time.I found that the source of the problem is the condition of iteration  ResultSet.next(). Have you an idea how can i ameliorate the performance and reduce spending time.

Comment: Which database are you using this with?

Answer (score 0):

ResultSet.next() actually works with networking undeneath and communicates with the server to bring more data once you have iterated over previous rows.

So two tips:

1. Increase the prefech size in the results query
2. Create indexes in the database. This will increase Database Performance which will make

Have a look also at these two links that deal with your issue and fetch size:

- http://www.precisejava.com/javaperf/j2ee/JDBC.htm#JDBC112

  -http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.3/org/eclipse/persistence/config/QueryHints.html#JDBC_FETCH_SIZE

Increasing the fetch size means less times to take data from the database. Resultset is like a buffer that fetches X number of rows and refetches once you have iterated over them.

Finally, you could attempt to use threads while splitting your one query into 4-5 queries that are done in separate threads concurrently.